# Cannot decode JSON with a single value

Tags: swift

I am trying to decode JSON with a single value.That value is without any key.

```
Alamofire
        .request(query, method: method, parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request as Any)
        switch response.result {

        case .success(_):
            let data = response.data
            guard let data = data else {
                throw CustomExceptions.invalidJSON("No response found.")
            }
            do {
                let result = try APIHelper.deserialize(type: type, from: data)
                print(result)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The JSON file contains only one value without any key i.e true.
In current case it's a boolean value. Result should be true.

But I am getting this error.

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
```

Comment: as per json parsing rules json must be start with dictionary so you need to   put that value with dictionary with key value formate otherwise it will not convert.

Comment: If it is just a single value why not just convert/cast it to a string, why try to decode it as json?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am writing a code where there are a lot of requests so to avoid repetition I wanted to use a single function to decode all kind of responses. It works in languages like Java where a single value that has no key can be deserialzed directly so I assumed there might be something I did wrong in my swift code.

Comment: Alamofire only support JSON response. You need to change the code in internal classes to support direct data-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decode a single value with the `Decodable` protocol because the underlying `JSONSerialization` API is called with *no options* so a collection type as root object is required.

That's exactly what the error message

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

says, `Decodable` does not allow to set any options like `allowFragments`